# converting PHP language to css

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am new to PHP (and coding in general) and struggling to find a way to edit my custom-style.php file.
I have a wordpress site and would like to modify the font-size of an element.

When I inspect the page via Developer tools (via Chrome), the full css of the custom-style.php file appears and I can see which areas I need to edit:

```html
/* HEIGHT MENU */

   header #logo { height: 86px;  }
   /*.open-nav { height: 86px; }
   .open-nav .text { line-height: 86px;  }*/
   header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) nav#main-nav > ul > li > a { line-height: 86px; }
   header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) nav#main-nav ul li > ul.sub-menu { top: calc(50% + 15px); }
   /*#page-body { padding-top: 206px; }*/
   header:after, header:before { top: -206px; height: 206px; } 
   header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) + #hero, header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) + #page-body { margin-top: 206px; }
   #header-filter, #header-share, #header-search { top: -206px;  min-height: 206px; }
   header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) #menu .open-filter, header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) #menu .open-share, header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) #menu .open-search, header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) #menu .menu-language { top: calc(43px + 2px); -webkit-transform: translateY(100%); -moz-transform: translateY(100%); -ms-transform: translateY(100%); -o-transform: translateY(100%); transform: translateY(100%); }
   
     @media only screen and (max-width: 781px) {
      header #logo { height: 30px;  }
      header:after, header:before { top: -90px; height: 90px; }
      header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) + #hero, header.header-open:not(.header-transparent) + #page-body { margin-top: 90px; }
     }
```

However when I try to  edit the same custom-style.php file on my server, the file appears like this:

```html
<?php 
$sr_prefix = "_sr";
header("Content-type: text/css");
$absolute_path = __FILE__;
$path_to_file = explode( 'wp-content', $absolute_path );
$path_to_wp = $path_to_file[0];
require_once( $path_to_wp . '/wp-load.php' );
?>

/* HEIGHT MENU */
<?php echo sr_custom_style_logo(); ?>
```

What am I missing here? How do I expand this code so I can make edits?

Comment: What is `sr_custom_style_logo();`?

Comment: That is probably a function the theme developer created. Look up child theme and modify your style.css to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of coding!  What you are seeing in Chrome is the result of running the PHP program.  What you are looking at on the server is the PHP program itself.  You're going to need to work your way through the program to find the variables or constants you want to change.  However!  When it comes to themed websites like Wordpress, these variables and constants are often already available to you through a configuration page.  If you prefer to wander through the code directly, get in the habit of making small changes then testing, back the changes out, make the next set of changes, then test, until you have an idea of how the original author designed his/her code.  As you can imagine, there's a lot you can break in there.  Jek has the right idea.  The `sr_custom_style_logo()` function probably contains the code you're looking for.